# How do I use plotmath to create subscript/superscript in a string from a list?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript, superscript, plotmath

I am creating multiple plots with parameter names in the ggtitle. Some of these have subscripts, superscripts or other plotmath characters. My parameters are stored in a param-list and are presented as strings in my ggplot function that I am looping into a lapply plotlist. I basically just want to insert "NO[3] (mg/l)", "NH[4]^+ (µg/l)" etc  from the param-list into my ggtitle(param) to create a title with these parameter names. At the same time I wish to have all [n] converted to subscripts, and all ^n converted to superscripts.

[This title is not well formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EMpN.png)

I have read about bquote and expression, but these assume I have an expression. Even if I create expressions from the strings, the bquote cannot handle the resulting name. I was hoping to be able to transform "NO[3] (mg/l)" into NO[3]~(mg/l) or something similar and then use bquote or expression. Is there a way to do this by creating smarter param-combinations that can be easily parsed (something like [[param]] in aes), or do I have to handle the parameter strings by seperating all problematic characters and then combining again with bquote or expression?

Grateful for any advice! :)

Comment: Try with e.g. `scales::label_parse()("NO[3] (mg/l)")`

Comment: `ggtext` offers a markdown-based syntax, e.g. `labs(title = "NO<sub>3</sub> (mg/l)")` or  `labs(title = "NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup> (µg/l)")` https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/theme_elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for suggesting filters. I ended up just gsub:ing blanks for ~ and comma's for points, and then parsing the parameter strings. it ended upp just fine without having to use more filters.

This was my final code, and param_exp could then be used within ggtitle:

```
if (grepl("\\[|\\^", param)) { #only use if [ or ^ is detected
    param_exp <- parse(text=gsub(" ", "~", gsub(",", "." ,param)))
} else {
    param_exp = param
}
```